# Priority of throws and throw for same exception

Tags: java, exception

I was curious which one of `throws` and `throw` has higher priority, when it comes to the same type of exception (although this does not seem likely to occur in real-life examples). Below is the example I came across:

```
public void sample() throws ArithmeticException{
    //Statements

    .....

    //if (Condition : There is an error)
    ArithmeticException exp = new ArithmeticException();
    throw exp;
    ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? The `throws` in the method header declares which exception(s) might be (or can expected to be) thrown. The `throw` is where an exception will actually be thrown. There is no priority, because `throws ArithmeticException` doesn't _do_ anything

Comment: @Trobbins I was wondering, if there is an exception, if we declare it using `throws`, and define it using `throw` in the method body, does it get thrown by `throws` or `throw` if there is really this exception by runtime (in this case if we have an alrithmetic exception)?

Comment: _"does it get thrown by throws or throw"_ `throws` doesn't _do_ anything. Nothing happens until `throw exp;`

Comment: First, `throws` doesn’t *do* anything, second `throw` doesn’t *define* anything. `throw` is the statement that will throw. point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `throws` means that a method **can** throw an exception. A method that declares an exception does **not** have to throw them. It is just that they **can** be thrown. Thus, the compiler enforces the caller to catch those exceptions.

So `throw` is actually really throwing an exception. It can be used when there is no `throws` declaration, too.

Comment: "The keyword `throws` means that a method can `throw` an exception. Those are called checked exception. " I am confused as the `ArithmeticException` is not a checked exception...

Comment: @Ischuetze I was wondering, if there is an exception, if we declare it using throws, and define it using throw in the method body, does it get thrown by throws or throw if there is really this exception by runtime (in this case if we have an alrithmetic exception)?

Comment: `throws` just says that the exception can be thrown by the method. `throw` instead really makes it thrown.